# insert select with autogenerate column

Tags: ms-access, autogeneratecolumn

I have 2 similar tables and they have a column with attribute autogenerate
when I do : insert int target (col2,col3....) select col2,col3 from source
I get an error : probabably because col1 (autogenerate) is not null and not specified with insert
the col1 can not be transferred, because when executed twice, you would get duplicates....
I tried with wizard interface : but also ignored col1 and get same error
is there a possibility to overcome this problem with an option like in other db : identityignore..
thanks for all update/help Best regards, Guy

Comment: Is the column that is "autogenerate" actually an Autonumber field? What error message do you get? What is your SQL statement?

Comment: Why are you copying col2, col3 from one table to another?

Comment: the column is autonumber. I have a table with new data and a table with cumulated data. now I want to transfer new data to consolidated table.  the statement is insert into target (col2,col3...-)  select col2,col3 from source..    and not specifying col1=autonumber..  the message is very generic : could not insert because of not null, duplicate........